# How to drag and drop custom file using Cypress

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

I'm currently working on doing a drag and drop file where I basically have a file format called BMPROJ which contains a JSON. However, the website works that it needs to drag and drop the file as a BMPROJ file to be able to accept it (A raw json would not work) and inside the BMPROJ it is just a simple json file.

The reason I am writing here is that I have a code that is following together with using [cypress-file-upload](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload):

```js
cy.get('.mod-view-3d').attachFile({
    filePath: 'C:/Users/MY-PC/Desktop/BOM/1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-K51H1528FH1.BMPROJ',
    encoding: 'utf-8'
}, {
    force: true,
    subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'
});
```

And what I want to do is to drag and drop the file **1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-K51H1528FH1.BMPROJ** however the error I do get is:

```
A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:

> cypress\fixtures\C:\Users\MY-PC\Desktop\BOM\1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-16ED72F30C1E.BMPROJ
> cypress\fixtures\C:\Users\MY-PC\Desktop\BOM\1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-16ED72F30C1E.BMPROJ{{extension}}

Cypress looked for these file extensions at the provided path:

> .json, .js, .coffee, .html, .txt, .csv, .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff, .zip

Provide a path to an existing fixture file.
```

My question is - How am I able to drag and drop the file?

Answer (score 2):

For your issue `BMPROJ` extension is not recognized as valid file extension so Cypress is throwing an error.

Cypress 9.3.0 added new commands called `.selectFile()`, to select files in an HTML5 input element or simulate dragging a file into the browser. You can try simulating drag and drop.

Please take a reference of [this document](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile#Syntax) and modify your command.

```js
cy.get('.mod-view-3d').selectFile({
  contents: Cypress.Buffer.from('file contents'),
  fileName: ${name of your file},
  lastModified: Date.now(),
})
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for the information! I do have a problem where I am not sure what I should replace 'file contents' with

Comment: Also you mentioned that my file is not valid, does it mean that there is basically no chance?

Comment: If you look at the error, supported formats are mentioned. So I believe `BMPROJ` won't be accepted. Hence you can try to simulate drop file using newly supported native command, `.selectFile()`. There isn't 100% chance but it's worth trying.

Comment: I tried to change to `cy.get('.mod-view-3d').selectFile(
        'C:/Users/MY-PC/Desktop/BOM/1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-16ED72F30C1E.BMPROJ', 
      {
        action: 'drag-drop',
        log: true
      })` and I do not get any error however it doesn't add anything on the webpage. So basically its a success log but nothing on the page has been added. Am I doing something wrong perhaps?

Comment: Your code seems correct. It should work. Is there any kind of validation after file is uploaded?

Comment: By checking the console and network logs. There is nothing, I tried to drag and drop manually on the cypress window and that worked fine. So it must be something that the script itself doesn't do the drag and drop on the page

Comment: command is working fine for me. You can find working example at https://github.com/krishhna123/cypress-examples/tree/main/cypress-file-upload/cypress/integration

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't have to do with my file. I know that using format as json, png works most likely but not with BMPROJ. Not sure if it has to do that it tries to drag and drop to a javascript frame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241272/discussion-between-protractornewbie-and-krishna).

Answer (score 1):

You could move that file into the `/cypress/fixtures` folder, for purposes of testing that would be logical - everything test related within the cypress folder.

Or try raw mode of cypress-file-upload, but the file must still be within the project folder (where `cypress.json` is).

```js
const filePath = '1BC475E2-7578-471A-AD23-16ED72F30C1E.BMPROJ'  // in project root

cy.readFile(filePath, 'binary')
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]').attachFile({
      fileContent,
      filePath,
      encoding: 'binary',
      lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
    },
    { 
      subjectType: 'drag-n-drop', 
      force: true
    })
    .trigger('change')  // or 'input', 'dragend', 'drop' may work
  })
```

Note that cypress-file-upload cannot work with files outside the project root. Krishna's example gist works because his upload file is within the project.

Your file can be named anything, because in raw mode you are explicitly telling cypress-file-upload what encoding you have - it does not need to infer the type from the extension.

Comment: Hello Fody! After testing your snippet (https://i.imgur.com/0L9ayuz.png) the test seems to go fine as I can see but nothing happens on the webpage. Don't we need to add some sort of "drag and drop" call as well? also you have a typo in readfile (should be readFile)

Comment: I think any action after attachFile() is app dependent. Try chaining `.trigger('change')` after `.then(fileContent => {...})`, or other events like 'input', 'dragend', 'drop' - it depends on how the programmer set things up.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add that to your example? :)

Comment: Unfortunate that did not work for me :( Looks like something is spooky... not sure what really.

Comment: One more thing to try, add an options object within `.attachFile()` (2nd parameter), to specify 'drag-n-drop'. With that mode, cypress-file-upload searches for the input element within `'.mod-view-3d'`. You can also inspect the DOM to make sure the input is indeed under the element you are selecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241272/discussion-between-protractornewbie-and-krishna)

Comment: It looks like nothing happend here either https://i.imgur.com/N7cqJ0K.png

Comment: Ideally, you could find out from the developer what events are being used. Or may be able to get the info from inspecting the input element, looking at the "Event listeners" tab.

Comment: Is it possible for you to join the chat so we can talk and I could probably guide you more into how I am doing it?